# What is a ScalaSignature?

Tags: java, scala, scalac, scala-compiler

When decompiling Scala files to Java code, one often comes across classes that are annotated with the `ScalaSignature`s. These seem to only have one annotation value, a somewhat encoded String. Why does the Scala Compiler create such an odd construct, instead of using custom `Attribute`s in the `class` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Storage of pickled Scala signatures in class files](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sid/10.html#):

> The
>   legacy
>   method for storing signatures
>   as attributes
>   is simultaneously more elegant,
>   more compact (about 15%) and simpler
>   than that using annotations.
>   However, to access
>   the pickled signature
>   in attributes
>   requires
>   obtaining and parsing
>   the
>   entire class file.
>   Because annotations are recognized by the JVM, the new method allows retrieving
>   pickled
>   signature
>   bytes
>   directly from within
>   a running Scala program
>   by using Java reflection.
>
> The new method
>   is
>   part of an ongoing development to write
>   a
>   good
>   Scala
>   reflection
>   library.
>   Java reflection
>   views
>   Scala
>   programs in
>   a simplified Java-centric way. To give a
>   Scala-centric view of the reflected program, information provided by Java reflection must
>   be completed
>   with information found in
>   Scala signatures.
>   The
>   legacy
>   storage method
>   would have required
>   all
>   class files to be parsed
>   again
>   —
>   the JVM has parsed them already
>   and exposes most of their content through reflection.
>   The new storage
>   method allows
>   accessing
>   pickled Scala signatures
>   in the same way than other reflective information is
>   obtained, making the new Scala reflection library simpler and faster.
>
> Whilst the Scala reflection library will not be part of the 2.8 release, it is
>   desirable
>   that
>   existing
>   2.8 class files are compatible with the new reflection library when it becomes
>   available.
>   Furthermore, since 2.8 class files are incompatible with those of 2.7
>   in any case,
>   changing
>   the method of storing
>   signatures
>   in 2.8
>   will not require
>   another
>   binary-incompatible
>   class file format
>   change
>   shortly after.