# How can I assert if a class extends "AnyVal" using ArchUnit

Tags: scala, archunit

I want to write an [arch unit](https://www.archunit.org/) test to assert that a class extends `AnyVal` type.

```scala
val rule = classes().should().beAssignableTo(classOf[AnyVal])
val importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("a.b.c")

isAnyVal.check(importedClasses) // Always returns true
```

The above code doesn't actually catch anything and passes for classes that don't extend `AnyVal` also.

Comment: Why not enforcing this on type-level and getting rid of the need of testing? Especially since compile-time `AnyVal`s don't map exactly into classes extending `AnyVal` interface?

Comment: I want that devs, while creating a new type, always ensure that it extends AnyVal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classOf[AnyVal]` is `java.lang.Object`, so you are just asking that all classes extend `Object`, which they do.

From [ArchUnit user guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html):

> It does so by analyzing given Java bytecode, importing all classes into a **Java** code structure.

I was hoping you'd get `Class` etc. and could go into Scala reflection from there, even if you wouldn't get the nice DSL, but they use their own API instead.

So to answer Scala-specific questions, it would need to parse [`@ScalaSignature` annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267199/what-is-a-scalasignature) and that would probably be a very large effort for the developers (not to mention maintenance, or dependence on specific Scala version at least until Scala 3).

Comment: Is there any way I can use pure reflection to achieve this?

Comment: Try to get list of class names from `val importedClasses`, then load them with Scala reflection.