# NullPointerException when accessing case object in map

Tags: scala

I am receiving a NullPointerException which I believe is due to the way objects are initialised but cannot find any supporting documentation.

I have this example code which illustrates the problem in Scala 2.12.7, I have found repeatable results in Scala 3.1.3 also:

```scala
abstract class Item(val collectionName: String)

abstract class ItemCollection(val name: String)

object TechItems extends ItemCollection("tech") {
  // referencing 'name' from 'ItemCollection' superclass
  case object TV extends Item(collectionName = name)

  val items: Map[String, Item] = Map("tv" -> TV)
}

object Test1 extends App {
  // prints 'tech'
  println(TechItems.items.get("tv").map(_.collectionName))
}

object Test2 extends App {
  // prints 'tech'
  println(TechItems.TV.collectionName)

  // throws NullPointerException
  println(TechItems.items.get("tv").map(_.collectionName))
}
```

When running `Test1`, the code behaves as you'd expect. When running `Test2`, we now receive a `NullPointerException` when accessing the map after accessing the `TV` object directly.

When I no longer reference a field from the superclass, the issue no longer occurs:

```scala
...

object TechItems extends ItemCollection("tech") {
  // using String instead of reference to superclass field
  case object TV extends Item(collectionName = "mycollection")

  val items: Map[String, Item] = Map("tv" -> TV)
}

...

object Test2 extends App {
  // prints 'mycollection'
  println(TechItems.TV.collectionName)

  // prints 'Some(mycollection)'
  println(TechItems.items.get("tv").map(_.collectionName))
}
```

My current understanding of how `TechItems` is initialised:

1. We access `TechItems.TV.collectionName` which begins initialising `TechItems`
2. An `ItemCollection("tech")` is created whose fields are then available inside of `TechItems` (depending on access modifiers of said superclass fields)
3. `TV` is initialised and references the superclass field `name`
4. `items` is initialised and references `TV` as a value for key `"tv"`

I am sure that understanding is wrong but that is what I am here to learn.

My current theory for the NullPointerException:

1. We access `TechItems.TV.collectionName` which begins initialising `TechItems`
2. `items` is initialised alongside `TV`, but `items` captures an uninitialised `TV` as `null`
3. Our access to `TechItems.TV.collectionName` returns the value of `"tech"`
4. `TechItems.items.get("tv")` returns `Some(null)` because `TV` at the point of initialising `items` was `null`, due to not being initialised.
5. `NullPointerException` is thrown

To me it feels like a somewhat farfetched theory. I am sure my lack of understanding is shown here and there is an explanation in some documentation that I have failed to find. Why do I get this `NullPointerException`? What is the initialisation order? And why does removing the reference to a superclass field affect this initialisation?

Comment: You can use `lazy val items` in this case, but it does not answer your quesion

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is a good one!
Here is what I think is going on ...

Consider this "pseudo-java" code, that I believe more-or-less accurately reflects what is actually happening in the JVM:

```
class TechItems extends ItemCollection {
    static MODULE = new TechItems("tech")
    static class TV extends Item {
       static MODULE = new TV(TechItems.MODULE.name)
    }
    val items = Map("tv" -> TV.MODULE)
}
```

So, now, when you do `print(TechItems.TV.MODULE.collectionName)`,
`TechItems.MODULE` gets constructed, because we need to pull `name` out of it to create `TV`.

This constructor, runs to the `Map("tv" -> TV.MODULE)` line, and puts `null` into the map (`TV.MODULE` is still null - we are only figuring out what to pass to its constructor.

If you use `"mycollection"` instead of `name`, it becomes
`static MODULE = new TV("mycollection")`, which doesn't trigger `TechItems` constructor.

What happens when you don't access `TV` before looking at `items`? Well, in that case, `TechItems.MODULE` gets initialized *first*, so, by the time you get to the `new TV` thing, as part of constructing the `items`, `TechItems.MODULE.name` is already available, so `TV.MODULE` can be created and put into the map.

Answer (score 0):

Dima is right. In fact, without inspecting the decompiled code, it would be harder to figure out what is happening under the hood. For simplicity, let's assume you just do these 2 calls in order (it will reproduce the issue):

```
println(TechItems.TV)        // prints 'TV'
println(TechItems.items)     // prints 'Map(tv -> null)'
```

Now let's decompile the code and show only the relevant parts. (I removed unnecessary code to be easier to follow) First these calls:

```
Predef$.MODULE$.println((Object)Main.TechItems$.TV$.MODULE$);
Predef$.MODULE$.println((Object)Main.TechItems$.MODULE$.items());
```

This was our `Main`. Now `TechItems` and `TV`:

```
public static class TechItems$ extends ItemCollection {
    public static final TechItems$ MODULE$;
    private static final Map<String, Main.Item> items;
        
    static {
        MODULE$ = new TechItems$();
        items = (Map)Predef$.MODULE$.Map().apply((Seq)ScalaRunTime$.MODULE$.wrapRefArray(
                 (Object[])new Tuple2[] { 
                     Predef.ArrowAssoc$.MODULE$.$minus$greater$extension(
                     Predef$.MODULE$.ArrowAssoc((Object)"tv"), (Object)TV$.MODULE$) 
                 }));
    }

    public Map<String, Main.Item> items() {
        return TechItems$.items;
    }
    
    public TechItems$() {
        super("tech");
    }

    public static class TV$ extends Main.Item implements Product, Serializable {
       public static final TV$ MODULE$;
            
       static {
           Product.$init$((Product)(MODULE$ = new TV$()));
       }

       public TV$() {
           super(TechItems$.MODULE$.name());
       }
}
```

When calling our first `println` statement we trigger the evaluation of `TechItems.TV` which translates to `TechItems$.TV$.MODULE$`. The `MODULE$` is just a static final reference of `TV` that gets initialized in the static block of `TV`. To get initialized, it starts executing the static block, which in turn calls `TV`'s constructor, `new TV$()` which in turn triggers the call to `TechItems` via: `super(TechItems$.MODULE$.name());`

This is the part where it gets interesting: `TechItems$.MODULE$` is just the static final reference of `TechItems`, that was not yet referenced, so it was not yet initialized. Again, in the same manner, to get initialized, the static block of `TechItems` gets called. But this time the static block is different: It has to initialize `TechItems$.MODULE$` and `items` as well, because both reside in the same static block.

Since we are in the middle of initializing `TV$.MODULE$`, and we just called `items` which requires the same reference - that we have not yet finished initializing, this reference is `null` at this point in time, so `items` is executed having `TV$.MODULE$` as `null`.

After this, the static block of `TechItems$.MODULE$` finishes, the static block of `TechItems.TV` finishes and we get printed `TV` at the console. The second `print` becomes self-explanatory. The call to `items()` returns `TechItems$.items` that we just evaluated in the previous call to `TV`, so `items` return `Map(tv -> null)` which gets printed.

**Observations:**

- Using `case object TV extends Item(collectionName = name)` is precisely what triggers the issue. The logical idea is that, you do not want to evaluate `items` before `TV` finishes evaluation. So one can do 2 things: 1 - either not call `TV` before first calling `items` or just `TechItems` - which will trigger the evaluation of `TV`, and thus the correct initialization of `items` - or 2 (better solution) - delay evaluation of `items` as much as possible, until you really needed.

  Naturally - the solution to the second point is to make `items` a `lazy val`. If we do this, the issue goes away, because `items` will no longer be evaluated unless explicitly referenced by us, and it will no longer trigger evaluation when calling just `TV`. And if we call `items` first, it will trigger `TV`'s evaluation first. I can't show you the difference in the decompiled code because only the [ScalaSignature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267199/what-is-a-scalasignature) differs: keywords like `lazy` are implemented as "pickled" signature bytes since these are easily picked up by the JVM through reflection.
- Changing it to `case object TV extends Item(collectionName = "mycollection")` is also a fix. Since you no longer call `super(TechItems$.MODULE$.name());` from `TV` at all, `items`'s evaluation is no longer triggered when just `TV` is called. The call to `TV`'s constructor becomes `super("mycollection")`, so the second `print` would then correctly evaluate `items` to `Map(tv -> TV)`. This is why the `null` goes away when you change it.
- This is an example of a *circular dependency*: `TV` "kind of" needs `items` and `items` needs `TV` - and the order of initialization really makes the difference between a working code and a code that throws nulls at unexpected times.
  Since `TV` is presumably initialized `lazy`, making `items` `lazy` as well should theoretically remove the [circular dependency](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html#circular-dependencies).
  An `object` definition in Scala behaves much like a `lazy val` with an annonymous class, that gets initialized  on demand, the first time it is used.

  So the first instinct when you see an `object` inside another `object`, is to assume the former `object` will be lazily initialized (unless explicitly referenced). Because `items` does reference `TV` explicitly, even if you don't call `TV` explicitly, `TV` will be evaluated either when referencing just `TechItems` or directly `items`, whichever comes first, because both are in the same static context, as we saw.